# How to make a custom space border by using objective-chipmunk physics engine?

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem with customizing the border of of 2D-physics engine with objective-chipmunk:

```
[space addBounds:self.view.bounds thickness:10.0f elasticity:0.5f friction:0.5f layers:CP_ALL_LAYERS group:CP_NO_GROUP collisionType:borderType];
```

How can I customize the bounds? (what I want is to simulate physics objects in a part of entire screen)

I've tried to use:

```
[space addBounds:CGRECMake(50.0f,50.0f,100.0f,100.0f) thickness:10.0f elasticity:0.5f friction:0.5f layers:CP_ALL_LAYERS group:CP_NO_GROUP collisionType:borderType];
```

But it doesn't work at all...

Any answer will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a relatively simple method. I really just adds 4 segment shapes for you and sets up their collision properties and locations. It was added as a library routine in Objective-Chipmunk because it's one of those things that half of all games end up doing.

It's a relatively simple method. I really just adds 4 segment shapes for you and sets up their collision properties and locations. It was added as a library routine in Objective-Chipmunk because it's one of those things that half of all games end up doing.

The original source is as follows. It just adds segments between all of the corners of the boxes.

```
static ChipmunkStaticSegmentShape *
boundSeg(ChipmunkBody *body, cpVect a, cpVect b, cpFloat radius, cpFloat elasticity,cpFloat friction, cpLayers layers, cpGroup group, cpCollisionType collisionType)
{
    ChipmunkStaticSegmentShape *seg = [ChipmunkStaticSegmentShape segmentWithBody:body from:a to:b radius:radius];
    seg.elasticity = elasticity;
    seg.friction = friction;
    seg.layers = layers;
    seg.group = group;
    seg.collisionType = collisionType;

    return seg;
}

- (void)addBounds:(CGRect)bounds thickness:(cpFloat)radius
    elasticity:(cpFloat)elasticity friction:(cpFloat)friction
    layers:(cpLayers)layers group:(cpGroup)group
    collisionType:(cpCollisionType)collisionType;
{
    cpFloat l = bounds.origin.x - radius;
    cpFloat r = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width + radius;
    cpFloat b = bounds.origin.y - radius;
    cpFloat t = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height + radius;

    [self add:boundSeg(_staticBody, cpv(l,b), cpv(l,t), radius, elasticity, friction, layers, group, collisionType)];
    [self add:boundSeg(_staticBody, cpv(l,t), cpv(r,t), radius, elasticity, friction, layers, group, collisionType)];
    [self add:boundSeg(_staticBody, cpv(r,t), cpv(r,b), radius, elasticity, friction, layers, group, collisionType)];
    [self add:boundSeg(_staticBody, cpv(r,b), cpv(l,b), radius, elasticity, friction, layers, group, collisionType)];
}
```

Also, when you say it doesn't work at all, what do you mean? Like there don't seem to be any bounds anywhere or they don't show up where you expect? Are you certain that your rendering coordinates are where you expect?- (void)addBounds:(CGRect)bounds thickness:(cpFloat)radius

Also, when you say it doesn't work at all, what do you mean? Like there don't seem to be any bounds anywhere or they don't show up where you expect? Are you certain that your rendering coordinates are where you expect?- (void)addBounds:(CGRect)bounds thickness:(cpFloat)radius

Comment: Would you be kind enough to post a sample spinet here to guide me through this problem. You should have seen my post in chipmunk forum. My doubt is what is segment shapes (any example?) and what is the meaning of addBounds?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to objective-c and also chipmunk :-)

Comment: Moreover, it would be a big thanks if you can guide me through the set-up of chipmunk space, chipmunk segment space (wall) and chipmunk bodies as I'm afraid that I have done something stupid in my code.

Comment: I added the source of the method above as a guide. If you need help with the basics, there are a number of tutorials on the documentation page: http://chipmunk-physics.net/documentation.php